# What about "that"?

Tags: clauses, relative-pronouns

Consider this example:

> That 'that' that that guy used was ungrammatical.

The four instances of "that" are all grammatical, but have different functions/meanings. What is the function/meaning of each "that"?

Comment: [this page](http://www.englishclub.com/ref/esl/Power_Of_Seven/Seven_Thats_2948.htm) might be a start.

Comment: Determiner, noun, relative pronoun, determiner.

Comment: Although there's an argument to be made that that *that* that Damkerng refers to as a relative pronoun is in fact the same marker of subordination we find in non-relatives and is not a relative pronoun at all.

Comment: @snailplane There is indeed such an argument; but it should be noted that some, at least, find it to be synchronically specious and diachronically indefensible. :)

Comment: Compare to: *"That thing that those guys used was ungrammatical."*

Comment: You might also be interested in: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo

Comment: @CoolHandLouis As to which comment?

Comment: @CoolHandLouis I think that it makes it obvious as to what type of function the corresponding "that" in the original version is doing.

Comment: @CoolHandLouis Feel free to analyze my example via your answer post to demonstrate why it is wrong. :)

Comment: @CoolHandLouis F.E. has made his point clearly enough already. Did you misread his comment? *Those*, like the fourth *that*, is a distal demonstrative determinative.  *Those guys* is syntactically very similar to *that guy*.  It makes it clear which *that* is being used by substitution with a less ambiguous word of the same type with the same function.

Comment: @snailplane, Thanks! A slight change to FE's sentence helps demonstrate the function of every *that* in the sentence: *This_1 thing_2 that_3 those_4 guys used was ungrammatical.*

Comment: @StoneyB CGEL makes the argument you're likely familiar with on synchronic grounds (like McCawley, mostly distributional--*that* has much wider distribution but restrictions no *wh*-word has, such as always marking finite clauses, much like the subordinator *that*; also like the subordinator, it is often omissible; and also like the subordinator, it has no genitive form and cannot be the complement of a preposition), but see Otto Jespersen's *A Modern English Grammar on Historical Principles*, vol. 3 *Syntax*, Chapter 8, *Relative that*, for a diachronic argument with examples back to Chaucer.

Comment: I personally prefer synchronic analysis. Diachronic analysis, in one way or another, is used to "prove" the preference for a prescriptive approach, arguing for why certain forms are "inferior/superior," which forms are "central" and which forms are "aberrational," and what not. I find it interesting how a prescriptivist approach uses the language of Fascism in its argumentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be difficult for non-native English speakers to even understand the question (which is important since StackExchange is intended to be a resource).  So let's build up the semantics one "that" at-a-time, which, incidentally, will also answer the question.

- **1st That:** ***That*** flower looks pretty.  The first *that* is a demonstrative determiner, indicating *which flower* is being talked about.<sup>1</sup>
- **2nd That:** *That **"that"** should be capitalized.*  The second *that* is simply a reference to the word itself, so it is a noun.  For example, consider the following incorrectly capitalized sentence written by some student in a paper:  *John thought, "**that** is interesting."* A teacher, talking to the student, might point her finger at the word 'that' and say, "That 'that' should be capitalized."
- **3rd That:** *That milk **`that` he used** is sour.*<sup>2</sup> The 3rd *that* is a relative pronoun introducing a relative clause. Note that one can often remove *that* when used as a relative clause: *That milk **he used** is sour.* (See also, https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104512/is-this-a-relative-pronoun-or-conjunction.)
- **4th (last) That:** *That "that" `that` **that guy** used is ungrammatical.*  Here we can see the last *that* is again a determiner, indicating which guy is being talked about.  We can also eliminate the 3rd *that* (the relative pronoun):  *That "that" **that guy** used is ungrammatical.*

Note that, when spoken, the different *that's* are emphasized through varying volume and pauses.  Here's an approximate description: (Normal) That (louder and lyrical like two syllables) THAT (very short, like it's connected to the next *that* as one word) that (normal but louder than the first *that*) that guy used is ungrammatical.

---

<sup>1. The *Demonstrative determiners* are also popularly called *demonstrative adjectives*.  The latter nomenclature might have evolved as a mix of terms or a misnomer, but it's popular enough that it will likely remain in print (and on the Internet) for a long time.  See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61456/use-of-determiners-as-adjectives/61470#61470 and http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/~gpullum/grammar/detv_sli.pdf.</sup>

<sup>2. I've highlighted all instances of the relative pronoun 'that' with `grey background` so one can easily see where-it-is and where-it-isn't.</sup>

Comment: Someone may not conceive of this question, but it is a useful example and it helps sort out how these things work. It's also pretty interesting, I think :)

Comment: Awesome explanation, btw. I only take issue in saying the third "that" is a relative pronoun. A subordinating conjunction subordinates a clause to another clause, such as SINCE:  "Since you've been gone, I can't stand the loneliness." But a relative clause ties a clause to a noun phrase:  "I like the cake THAT Linda brought." Which CAKE? The cake THAT Linda brought.

Comment: @Mark, I've corrected #3 as per your comment.  Thanks!

Comment: Another good example is the substitutions in: *This_1 thing_2 that_3 those_4 guys used was ungrammatical.* (Credit to @F.E. for the basic wording, though I've enhanced it to make it clear.)

Comment: @snailplane, thanks!  I've updated the answer to reflect this.